# header(" Location:") Redirecionamento a partir do diretorio raiz

Tags: php

Ola! Sou iniciante em php, e estou com problemas em utilizar
a função header(location).
Sempre que eu redireciono uma pagina, o caminho fica a partir do diretório da pagina atual! 
Ex: **Home/Forum/Imagens/** se tenho uma pagina dentro da pasta **/Forum/** e utilizo o `header("Location: Localhost/Home/Pagina.php")`para acessar uma pagina que esta no diretório **/Home/**, o link fica "Localhost/Forum/Home/Pagina.php", e logicamente ele não encontra, tem alguma forma de eu sempre setar a busca por diretório a partir do diretório raiz do site? para que as buscas sempre sejam feitas a partir de **/Home/** e não da pagina que tem a função Header()? e a mesma duvida se aplica ao form action, quando crio formulários php!
Agradeço dede já!

.htaccess

```
<files phpsysinfo.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi exatamente o que você está fazendo, mas faça assim:

```
header("Location: /Home/Pagina.php");
```

Answer (score -2):

estava com um problema do seguinte tipo , meu arquivo estava dentro de um diretório e a página que eu queria redirecionar estava em um repositório antes .

quando eu colocava desse jeito

header("location:../app_agenda/novo_cadastro.php?cadastro=1");
ele adicionava na URL tudo que esta acima somando com a url do repositorio atual

dava erro objeto nao encontrado!!!!

tive que fazer assim para funcionar :)

header("location:../../app_agenda/novo_cadastro.php?cadastro=1");